# Are there any spring integration tcp-inbound-channel-adapter examples?

Tags: spring, sockets, tcp, client, integration

Does anyone know of a simple example of tcp-inbound-channel-adapter CLIENT example using Spring? I want to create a simple TCP client that sends a short String to the server, and receives only one byte as answer and then closes the socket. Here is my bean definition:

```
<int-ip:tcp-connection-factory id="client2" type="client"
    host="localhost" port="${availableServerSocket}" single-use="true"
    so-timeout="10000" deserializer="climaxDeserializer"
    so-keep-alive="false" />

<int:service-activator input-channel="clientBytes2StringChannel"
    method="valaszjott" ref="echoService">
</int:service-activator>

<int:gateway
    service-interface="org.springframework.integration.samples.tcpclientserver.SimpleGateway"
    id="gw2" default-request-channel="gwchannel">
</int:gateway>
<int:channel id="gwchannel"></int:channel>
<int:object-to-string-transformer input-channel="gwchannel"
    id="clientbyte2string" output-channel="outputchannel">
</int:object-to-string-transformer>
<int:channel id="outputchannel"></int:channel>
<int-ip:tcp-outbound-channel-adapter channel="outputchannel"
    id="clientoutboundadapter" connection-factory="client2">
</int-ip:tcp-outbound-channel-adapter>
<int-ip:tcp-inbound-channel-adapter id="clientinboundadapter"
    channel="inputchannel" connection-factory="client2" />
<int:channel id="inputchannel"></int:channel>
<int:service-activator ref="echoService" method="valaszjott"
    input-channel="inputchannel" id="sa2">
</int:service-activator>
```

So, I use it this way from my main method :

```
....
SimpleGateway gateway = (SimpleGateway) context.getBean("gw2");
String result = gateway.send("foo");
....
```

And hereupon the client sends the `"foo" + /r/n` to the server. On the server side I get this message, and the server answers to client only one byte, `( 06H )` without `/r/n`. The client receives it, and the deserialiser finds it. Here is my deserialiser class :

```
@Component("climaxDeserializer")public class ClimaxDeserializer implements
Deserializer<Integer>{
    public Integer deserialize(InputStream arg0) throws IOException {
        int ertek;
        do{
            ertek = arg0.read();
            if ( ertek == 6){
                System.out.println("We have the ack byte !");
                return 1;
            }
        } while( ertek >= 0);
        return null;
    }
}
```

The deserialiser finds the ack byte, and the method returns an integer, the value is 1. 
The service activator points to this method :

```
public String valaszjott ( int success){
        System.out.println("Answer: " + success);
        if ( success == 1){
            return "OK";
        } else {
            return "NOK";
        }
    }
```

At this point every things work fine, and the `valaszjott` method prints out `Answer: 1`. But then the **result** parameter (in the `main` method ) never will get an `OK` or `NOK` string value, and the socket will remain open.

Where did I make a mistake ? If I change the `tcp-inbound-channel-adapter` and `tcp-outbound-channel-adapter` pair to `tcp-outbound-gateway` it works fine...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your mistake lays in the `multi-threading`.

The `<int:gateway>` invocation lives in the one Thread, but `<int-ip:tcp-inbound-channel-adapter>` is a `message-driven` component, which is a listener to the socket within it own Thread. And for the last one it doesn't matter, if you invoke your gateway or not: the server side always can send packets to that socket and your adapter will receive them.

For your `ack` use-case the `<tcp-outbound-gateway>` is the best solution, because with that your really have a `correlation` between request and reply. And having that you get a gain with multiple concurrent request.

Just with `<tcp-outbound-channel-adapter>` and `<tcp-inbound-channel-adapter>` there is no guaranty that replies will be returned from the server at the same order as requests have been sent.

Anyway in current your solution the `gateway` just doesn't know about reply and the last one can't be delivered to the `replyChannel` from request message headers.

From other side sockets won't be closed, because they are `cached` in the `<int-ip:tcp-connection-factory>`.

HTH